# Webservice call fails in a thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm implementing a busy indicator to work with my logon process using ProgressDialog, yes I know it's obsolete, but it satisfies the requirement.  The problem I'm having is that the call to the web service (yes, I know it's depreciated) fails, no error, nothing.  My code is:

```
private async void MyLogon()
{
    nDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    nDialog.SetMessage("Validating ...");
    nDialog.SetTitle("Log On");
    nDialog.Indeterminate = false;
    nDialog.SetCancelable(true);
    nDialog.Show();

    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        // Set the protocol
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // Instanciate the service
        DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface myService = new OMLDataInterfaceWeb.OMLDataInterface();
        // Fails here, cannot trap any error 
        result = myService.Logon(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password);
    }));
    thread.Start();

    while (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

There isn't much out there that addresses this issue, there was one post that suggested that one use `await` vis `wait`, but I already use that.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 1 Dont use a thread, just use a task, 2 you need to catch your error using a try/catch 3 if your service has an async call like `myService.LogoAsync` use that instead,

Comment: "fails" meaning what, exactly?  It returns null?  Have you tried catching an exception?

Comment: Doing a spin loop with a task to check the status of a thread...please no ;-) Convert it to a `await Task.Run(....)` and return what ever type `result` is (i.e. a `Task<ResultType>`) and add a try/catch on your `myService.Logon`

Comment: Also if its a rest api there are different kinds of rest api like put get post delete be sure that you are using the right type

Comment: Try Catch doesn't catch anything, so yes I've tried it.  When I step through the code with the debugger, when the `myService.Logon(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password)` (it's not a REST API, it ASMX) line is executed, the thread is exited, no error is generated.